# What are major differences between RequrieJs(AMD) and Browserify?

Tags: requirejs, browserify

I just want to clarify one thing. This is not a question on which one is better, that part I leave to someone else to discuss. I don't care about it. I've been asked this question on my job interview and I thought it might be useful to learn a bit more.